# How to programmatically bind Visibility on a button to INotifyPropertyChanged boolean property in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's what I got to so far:

```
System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("MyProperty");
binding.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.Converter = new System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter(); 
binding.Source = mySourceObject;

this.SetBinding(this.myButton.Visibility, binding);
```

but visibility is not a dependency property, so how can I do this?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx, `Visibility` certainly is a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: I've bound to a button's visibility before through XAML so you should be able to in code-behind.  I'm noticing the first line has a typo, is that in your code or just in the post?  It should be new System.Windows.Data.Binding you have Biding without the n.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
Button.VisibilityProperty
```

instead of

```
this.myButton.Visibility
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibilityproperty.aspx

Comment: that's great, but how would it know what the target is... if it's just a generic Button.VisibilityProperty.. how would it know to use my specific button?

Comment: because myButton should be setting the proeprty: this.myButton.SetValue(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, binding); See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx

Comment: i think you mean myButton.SetBinding(Button.VisibilityProperty, binding);

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass in the static Visibility dependency property itself (which `Button` inherits from `UIElement`), not the value of the property on the button instance, e.g.:

```
myButton.SetBinding(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, binding);
```